# Padding is invalid and cannot be removed while encryption decryption using AES

Tags: c#, angular6, aes, cryptojs

I'm working on AES encryption/decryption. I want to encrypt request from my angular app and send it to .net api and decrypt at api then encrypt the response from api side and send it to angular app and decrypt using AES.
But sometimes it gives me 'padding is invalid and cannot be removed' exception at api side.

Here is my angular typescript crypto service code:

```
aesEncrypt(keys: string, value: string) { // encrypt api request parameter with aes secretkey

    var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(keys);
    var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(keys);
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(value), key,
        {
            keySize: 128 / 8,
            //keySize: 128,
            iv: iv,
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,

        });

    return encrypted.toString();
}

aesDecrypt(keys: string, value: any) { // decrypt api response parameter with aes secretkey
    var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(keys);
    var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(keys);
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(value, key, {
        keySize: 128 / 8,
        //keySize: 128,
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });

    return JSON.parse(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
}
```

Here is my api crypto filter code:

Way 1:

```
public static string Encrypt(string key, string data)
{
    byte[] encryptedBytes = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(data);
    AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = AesCryptoServiceProvider(key);
    ICryptoTransform crypto = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
    byte[] secret = crypto.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length);
    crypto.Dispose();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(secret);
}

public static string Decrypt(string key, string encrypted)
{
    byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);
    AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = AesCryptoServiceProvider(key);
    ICryptoTransform crypto = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
    byte[] secret = crypto.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length);
    crypto.Dispose();
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(secret);
}

private static AesCryptoServiceProvider AesCryptoServiceProvider(string key)
{
    AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
    //aes.BlockSize = 128; //Not Required
    //aes.KeySize = 256; //Not Required
    //aes.KeySize = 128;
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key); //PSVJQRk9QTEpNVU1DWUZCRVFGV1VVT0 =
    aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key); //2314345645678765
    return aes;
}
```

Way 2:

```
public static string Encrypt(string key, string data)
{
    AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = AesCryptoServiceProvider(key);
    ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cs);
    streamWriter.Write(data);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    cs.FlushFinalBlock();
    byte[] cypherTextBytes = ms.ToArray();
    ms.Close();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(cypherTextBytes);
}

public static string Decrypt(string key, string encrypted)
{
    AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = AesCryptoServiceProvider(key);
    byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);
    ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor();
    byte[] plainText = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainText);
}

private static AesCryptoServiceProvider AesCryptoServiceProvider(string key)
{
    AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
    //aes.BlockSize = 128; //Not Required
    //aes.KeySize = 256; //Not Required
    //aes.KeySize = 128;
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key); //PSVJQRk9QTEpNVU1DWUZCRVFGV1VVT0 =
    aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key); //2314345645678765
    return aes;
}
```

I tried both the ways at api level but still it is giving me padding issue (sometimes, not always)

Comment: Can you provide an example of data that succeeds and and example that fails?

Comment: @theMayer Okay I need to debug for it but whenever I debug all the requests succeeds

Comment: @theMayer Sometimes same requests succeeds but sometimes it fails

Comment: @theMayer I'm sending json request like this `{"BU":2,"GEOCODE":124152,"CLIENTID":"CIPQ","REPCODE":"S0004","ENTRYNO":3484,"ROLE":1,"MONTH":"Oct-2019","FLAG":0}`

Comment: Please update the question to list reproduction steps (including the above).

Comment: You should convert the output base64.

Comment: @kelalaka while encrypting or decrypting? I'm converting my encrypted data to base64

Comment: What about angular? Am I missing?